# What are available methods for modeling startup survival rates?

Tags: python, survival-analysis

I am interested in modeling startup companies failure and success rates to describe what is the representative startup.

I have 40 companies in a dataset. Each company is represented as a list of all the investment financing rounds it has gone through. For example:

```
Company 1: Seed Round, Series A Round
Company 2: Seed Round, Series A Round, Series B Round
Company 3: Seed Round, Series A Round, Series B Round
Company 4: Seed Round, Series A Round, Series B Round, Series C Round
Company 5: Seed Round
Company 6: Series A Round, Series B Round
Company 6: Series A Round
```

And so on.

I can see that each round can be represented as a state in a Markov Chain, and transitions are only allowed from earlier stages to later stages. I can go from Seed to Series A, and from Series A to Series B, but not from Series B to Series A.

So we have N-order markov chains (production data has N <= 4).

The output I'm looking for is a binary tree chart showing each stage as a node and each node can either transition to the next node or to a final state meaning the company has failed.

This problem can also be seen as a real options model...

Any ideas on how to implement this model?

I can code in Python or Ruby (but I am no expert).

Comment: Does the data include the amount of funding? Are you trying to compute the probability of going to round N+1 given funding X at round N? Do you have any other info about the company (turnover, size, profit)?

Comment: I am trying to predict how many companies I will have to invest in if I raise a US$ x m fund. This depends on the likelihood of companies advancing through financing stages, and how much I will invest in a Seed, Series A, B, C... round. That way I know that I can invest in less companies if I go from investing 12% to 25% of the total amounted in each Series A a participated in rounds. The stochastic modelling im trying here is to calibrate the survival rates in the model.

Answer (score 4):

If the data you show are the only data that you have, then the Markov Chain is really boring: it is a linear chain, going from Round A to Round B to Round C, and all those states are connected to a base state (which is Death, or something).

You can directly calculate the transition probabilities from the data you have, since the number of companies that reached round N are **all companies that could have reached round N** (there is no alternative path).  The death probability at the previous stage is (1 - $P_{reaching N}$)

```
In [1]: raw_data = """
   ...: Company 1: Seed Round, Series A Round
   ...: Company 2: Seed Round, Series A Round, Series B Round
   ...: Company 3: Seed Round, Series A Round, Series B Round
   ...: Company 4: Seed Round, Series A Round, Series B Round, Series C Round
   ...: Company 5: Seed Round
   ...: Company 6: Series A Round, Series B Round
   ...: Company 6: Series A Round
   ...: """
In [2]: data_lines = raw_data.splitlines()[1:]
In [6]: key_vals = {}
In [12]: for line in data_lines:
             key, val = line.split(':')
             key = key.strip()
             vals = [v.strip() for v in val.split(',')]
             key_vals[key] = vals

In [13]: key_vals
Out[13]:
{'Company 1': ['Seed Round', 'Series A Round'],
 'Company 2': ['Seed Round', 'Series A Round', 'Series B Round'],
 'Company 3': ['Seed Round', 'Series A Round', 'Series B Round'],
 'Company 4': ['Seed Round',
  'Series A Round',
  'Series B Round',
  'Series C Round'],
 'Company 5': ['Seed Round'],
 'Company 6': ['Series A Round']}

In [14]: transitions = ['Seed Round', 'Series A Round', 'Series B Round', 'Series C Round']

In [19]: for transition in transitions:
    summed = 0
    for company, rounds in key_vals.iteritems():
        if transition in rounds:
            summed += 1
    prob = float(summed) / float(len(key_vals.keys()))
    death_prob = 1 - prob
    print "From previous to %s: probability %s" % (transition, prob)
    print "Death rate at %s: probability %s" % (transition, death_prob)

From previous to Seed Round: probability 0.833333333333
Death rate at Seed Round: probability 0.166666666667
From previous to Series A Round: probability 0.833333333333
Death rate at Series A Round: probability 0.166666666667
From previous to Series B Round: probability 0.5
Death rate at Series B Round: probability 0.5
From previous to Series C Round: probability 0.166666666667
Death rate at Series C Round: probability 0.833333333333
```

However, if you had some more features of each company, like the amount of money they received at each stage, or the profit they were making, then you could train a [decision tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree), e.g. with [this implementation in sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html), that told you, in simple words, "if a company arrived at round X with at least Y dollars raised and at least Z dollars of profit, then they are passing to the next round with 0.XX probability".  Which is, I think, what you are aiming at.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am aiming at. I have data on funding volume and timing on each round. I'll look into the links you posted and I'll try running the code. Thanks a lot for your help.